# HVAC indoor fan stuck buzzing

Tags: hvac, electric-motor, ball-bearing

My old Sanyo SAP-KRV123EHA had a noisy ball bearing in the indoor fan unit. Since Sanyo is no longer making these units I tried replacing the fan bearing with ceramic ones. After assembling the motor, it can spin freely when no power is on, but a humming sequence can be heard when powered by the control PCB. And the motor seems to be braked to stand still. My guesses are:

1. I broke a wire to the hall sensor
2. the capacitor is fried, but it shouldn't get firmly stuck because of that?

Any other ideas? Before I start chasing a new motor.

Motor disassembled:

[image: Motor]

Comment: You might try posting on electronics stack exchange instead... good luck.

Comment: In the end I got a replacement motor which worked out of the box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had broken one of the Hall sensor wires. In the end I got a new motor. Re-mounting the old one wasn't feasible since I had disassembled it by bending open the rolled/pressed metal enclosure.